# Are there non-constant independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that $X^2 + Y^2 \equiv 1$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, independence

Are there any independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that $X^2 + Y^2 \equiv 1$ and both $X$ and $Y$ are not constants with probability 1?

I tried parametrized functions such as $X = \sin{\theta}, Y = \cos{\theta}$, however it didn't really help, I'm not if there is any example. And if there exists one it must be tricky.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: i suspect  "non-constant" in this context means continuous random variables, right ?

Comment: @AhmadBazzi not necessarily, but I would also really like to see an example for continuous random variables.

Comment: Sounds interesting: X and Y are obviously not independent. So what is the trick behind the question?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze - so what is wrong with my example? In particular with $X$ and $Y$ i.i.d. $\pm \sqrt{\frac12}$ with equal probability?

Comment: @Henry Nothing is wrong. On the contrary, you have nicely explained the trick behing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: suppose you have any $k$, $p$, $q$ all strictly between $0$ and $1$.  Having them all $\frac12$ gives some symmetry but is not necessary.  Then suppose

- $X = +\sqrt k$ with probability $p$ and $X=-\sqrt k$ with probability $1-p$
- $Y = +\sqrt{1-k}$ with probability $q$ and $Y = -\sqrt{1-k}$ with probability $1-q$, independently of $X$

Then $X$ and $Y$ are independent, neither is almost surely constant, and $X^2+Y^2=1$ with probability $1$

Comment: Thanks! Do you know is there any example for continuous random variables?

Comment: @Swistack There will not be any examples for continuous random variables as you need both $X^2$ and $Y^2$ either to each be almost surely constant or to be dependent on each other.  I think that any example must be of this form